# Grub menu created without parentheses around devices

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

I am running Debian Stretch, but got the same thing with Jessie, and have been manually fixing it after `update-grub2`.

Here is an excerpt from grub.cfg after update:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-simple-a65403af-9c9f-45f9-a43a-178399e4fa64' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  c8d685c1-3188-42cb-9ac1-a5675d159759
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c8d685c1-3188-42cb-9ac1-a5675d159759
        fi
        echo    'Loading Xen 4.8-amd64 ...'
        if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
            xen_rm_opts=
        else
            xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
        fi
        multiboot       /xen-4.8-amd64.gz placeholder dom0_mem=1024M  ${xen_rm_opts}
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 ...'
        module  /vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=a65403af-9c9f-45f9-a43a-178399e4fa64 ro
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        module  --nounzip   /initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64
}
```

See the `root='hd1,msdos1'` has no brackets.  So this is invalid syntax and I end up at the grub prompt.  Everything works if I add the brackets in.

I just have the usual stuff in `grub.d`:

```
# ls /etc/grub.d
00_header  05_debian_theme  08_linux_xen  10_linux  30_os-prober  30_uefi-firmware  old  README
```

Does anyone know how the root device could be formatted incorrectly?

Comment: I have 8 Debian machines, physical and virtual. On all of them the *set root* statement is identical to yours, *i.e.* without parentheses, and they all boot correctly. Why do you say this is incorrect syntax, and how exactly does your boot fail? I have *grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta3-5*.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Interesting.  I need to double check - I ended up at the prompt and assumed the syntax was incorrect, and added the brackets in, but perhaps that wasn't the reason it worked next time.  I'll have to go back over my steps.

Comment: This is invalid syntax per the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Naming-convention). Every other occurrence of `set root=...` uses parentheses too.

Comment: Interesting, the syntax is invalid, but after checking other servers, I find it is consistent with what @MariusMatutiae has found.  So something else is causing my problem.